# Is there a way to buy a sink stopper clevis separately?

Tags: plumbing, sink

My bathroom sink stopper is broken because of a missing clevis. The rods are there, but nothing connects them. I can obviously replace the whole thing, but I would like to buy only a clevis if possible.

On Amazon and HD/Lowe's web sites they only sell full kits, not parts.

Is there a way to buy a clevis separately? (Not necessarily the sink stopper one -- anything that would solve the problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home Depot shows Delta #RP12516. It should be a somewhat universal part. Any brand should fit. If they don't stock it they can order it. I would first try a local hardware store they are likely to carry a store brand for less than a Delta part. You will also need the clip that attaches the rod to the pivot lever.